# How to know if a network error is fatal or not in UDP server written in C?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

In the code below:

```
static int recv_commands(uint16_t port) {
    int s, rc;
    struct sockaddr_in svr;
    char buf[1024];
 
    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        rc = errno;
        goto quit;
    }
    svr.sin_family      = AF_INET; 
    svr.sin_port        = port;
    svr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&svr, sizeof(svr)) < 0) {
        rc = errno;
        goto quit;
    }
    while(1) {
        if (recv(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0) < 0) {
            rc = errno;
            break;
        } 
        //TODO: process buf... 
    }
quit:
    close(s);
    return rc;
}
```

I would like to know what are the possible errors that could happen in **`recv(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)`**?  If error happens, shall I **continue** or **break** the while loop?
i.e. will the error be fatal so that when an error happen, further recv() is not feasible?

Comment: The `man` page of `recv` is listing all of the possible errors.

Comment: When `socket()` fails, you're calling `close()` on the result nonetheless, btw. Another thing I noticed that you call this a "UDP server", but UDP is connectionless and without a dedicated server and client. One is a sender and the other a receiver, just that.

Comment: On a UDP socket, the only listed `errno` values that are really unrecoverable are ones that you would get if you passed in an invalid socket argument (e.g. `EBADF`, `EFAULT`, `ENOTSOCK`, or `EOPNOTSUPPORT`).  I have occasionally seen my Mac get into a loop of `recv()` returning `ENOBUFS`, but I suspect that is caused by a bug in the MacOS networking stack, so I don't have any good recommendation for how to handle that.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the receiver is what I called "udp server".

Comment: @JeremyFriesner since bind() succeeds (otherwise the function quits), what you mean is that it is not possible for a UDP recv to fail, unless some really wired thing happen, e.g. something in the backend ruined "s" (the socket).  In another word, it is safe to ignore error checking for recv()?

Comment: @EugeneSh. new versions of operating systems sometimes add new errors

Comment: @user253751 Making it even less reasonable to list the possible errors *here*.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the  question doesn't say "which errors?", it says "how to know if ...?"

Comment: @user253751 Perhaps part of it. The other part is "*I would like to know what are the possible errors that could happen*"

Comment: @xrfang it's not safe to ignore error checking, since you could still get a recoverable error like `EINTR`.  And of course you need to always check the return value of `recv()` to know how many bytes were written into your buffer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I do not have to know all possible errors, I asked, if there are any "clever" way to know if an error is transient or fatal, without bothering about exactly what is the reason. But anyway, the discussion here is very helpful